# The Method values() is undefined for the type String Error

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am currently experimenting in Spring MVC, and right now I'm trying to create a class of constants to populate a drop down list.  The enum method is fine, but in my controller I get an error

"The method values() is undefined for the type String.

```
       List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<job>(

         Arrays.asList(job.values()));

         mav.addObject("jobList", jobList);
```

The error appears directly underneath .values() I have imported java.util.Enumeration so it's not that.  Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the values of the enum class `Job`, not call the `values` method on the `job` variable which in your case seems to be of type `String`.

Try:

```
List<Job> jobList = Arrays.asList(Job.values());
```

Comment: Does that replace the first 2 lines?

Comment: It replaces your ``jobList`` declaration